# How can I prevent Chrome from crashing through Selenium?

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium in node.js to test web pages in Chrome on Windows 11. I recently moved to a new laptop, and now my Chrome browser crashes as soon as the driver launches it. I am using Chrome and Chromedriver version 109.0.5414.74 (same as on the old machine), node.js v16.13.0, and selenium-webdriver v4.7.1. Outside of Selenium, Chrome is working fine. Here's the simple repro:

```
const { Builder } = require( 'selenium-webdriver' );
const chrome = require( 'selenium-webdriver/chrome' );

async function main() {
    const chrome_options = new chrome.Options()
    .addArguments( '--disable-gpu' );
    const driver = await new Builder()
    .forBrowser( 'chrome' )
    .setChromeOptions( chrome_options )
    .build();

    await driver.get( 'https://google.com/' );

    await driver.quit();
}

main()
.then( () => {
    console.log( 'Done' );
})
.catch( e => {
    console.error( `Error: ${e.message}` );
});
```

I only added the `disable-gpu` because of some google search results that said it was needed, and because the error message references GPU problems, but nothing's different without it. Here's the output from `node crash.js`:

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:53101/devtools/browser/701cedaa-d8e3-4541-9c9b-d22f53244ac4
[29204:3600:0124/223239.948:ERROR:display_layout.cc(551)] PlacementList must be sorted by first 8 bits of display_id
[29204:3600:0124/223240.003:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(985)] GPU process launch failed: error_code=18
[29204:3600:0124/223240.038:ERROR:display_layout.cc(551)] PlacementList must be sorted by first 8 bits of display_id
[29204:3600:0124/223240.177:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(215)] [22:32:40.176] USB: usb_service_win.cc:415 Could not read device interface GUIDs: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2)
[29204:3600:0124/223240.179:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(215)] [22:32:40.178] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1046 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
[29204:3600:0124/223240.179:ERROR:usb_descriptors.cc(141)] Failed to read length for configuration 1.
[29204:3600:0124/223240.180:ERROR:usb_descriptors.cc(100)] Failed to read all configuration descriptors. Expected 2, got 1.
[29204:3600:0124/223240.181:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(215)] [22:32:40.180] USB: usb_device_win.cc:96 Failed to read descriptors from \\?\usb#vid_17ef&pid_3082#101b74e97#{a5dcbf10-6530-11d2-901f-00c04fb951ed}.
[29204:3600:0124/223240.181:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(215)] [22:32:40.181] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1046 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
[29204:3600:0124/223240.190:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(215)] [22:32:40.190] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1046 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
[29204:3600:0124/223240.191:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(215)] [22:32:40.192] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1046 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
[29204:3600:0124/223240.191:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(215)] [22:32:40.193] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1046 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
[29204:3600:0124/223240.222:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(215)] [22:32:40.232] Bluetooth: bluetooth_adapter_winrt.cc:1164 RequestRadioAccessAsync failed: RadioAccessStatus::DeniedByUserWill not be able to change radio power.
[29204:3600:0124/223240.238:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(215)] [22:32:40.240] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1046 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
[29204:3600:0124/223240.238:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(215)] [22:32:40.247] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1046 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
[29204:3600:0124/223240.238:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(985)] GPU process launch failed: error_code=18
[29204:3600:0124/223240.457:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(985)] GPU process launch failed: error_code=18
[29204:3600:0124/223240.598:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(985)] GPU process launch failed: error_code=18
[29204:3600:0124/223240.739:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(985)] GPU process launch failed: error_code=18
[29204:3600:0124/223240.865:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(985)] GPU process launch failed: error_code=18
[29204:3600:0124/223240.881:FATAL:gpu_data_manager_impl_private.cc(440)] GPU process isn't usable. Goodbye.
Error: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.
  (chrome not reachable)
  (The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

How can I tell why this is crashing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error message indicates that there is a problem with the GPU process launch. The `error_code=18` suggests that the GPU process has crashed, which is causing the Chrome browser to crash as well. This is likely due to a compatibility issue between the version of Chrome and the GPU driver on your new laptop.

You could try **updating the GPU driver** on your new laptop to see if that resolves the issue.

Alternatively, you could try **using a different version** of **Chrome** or **Chromedriver** that is known to be **compatible with the GPU driver** on your new laptop. You should also check if there any other software running on your new laptop that could be **conflicting with Selenium** and **Chrome**.

Also, try running your script with `--no-sandbox` option to see if it works.

```
const chrome_options = new chrome.Options()
  .addArguments("--disable-gpu")
  .addArguments("--no-sandbox");
```

Comment: I thought I had tried adding the `--no-sandbox` switch but it seems that I had not. Once I added this, the crash went away and my tests are passing again. Thanks for your help!